# bash create file every 10 minutes

Tags: bash, cat

I want to create a file every 10 minutes, after the file has been created it will be overwritten with a new name by another programme so a new one should be created by the script below:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 
while true
do
    cat >> trn 
    echo creating trn
    sleep 600   
done
```

when I run this, it creates the first file, doesn't echo the statement then stays in a loop without creating any more files.

Comment: There's no need to write this script. Try to type in your bash `watch -n 600 touch trn`

Comment: `cat` waits for stdin indefinitely.

Comment: @Qback, the `watch` command doesn't do this in macOS or bsd.

Comment: How about a [cronjob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)? I'd recommend `crontab` over `watch` if the task should last a long time (e.g. multiple days)  and/or survive reboots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use `cat >> trn`  for that. It is actually blocking execution of your script (awaiting user input)!

You can use instead (for instance)

- `touch trn` or `>> trn` (will create 'trn' file with empty content, only if doesn't already exist)
- `echo > trn` (will create / overwrite 'trn' file with one newline character content)
- `echo -n > trn` or `printf ''` (more portable) or simply `> trn` (will create / overwrite 'trn' file with empty content)

thanks to @CharlesDuffy for his enlightning comments. [Info here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) on better portability of `printf ''` over `echo -n` .

---

If your system supports `watch` command, then there is this much simpler option  that replaces your whole script (credits to @Qback in comments) :

```
watch -n 600 touch trn
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: no it's an answer. The `cat >> trn` is what is blocking the script.

Comment: The `watch` command is OS-specific. Even if answers are OS- or platform-specific (which this one is not), answers that are portable have greater benefit to the larger community.

Comment: @ghoti : you're right, (just realized it now while testing on my Git-bash on Windows...). However, OP's script with the correction provided in my answer is portable, isn't it ?

Comment: `>> trn` would suffice, or `> trn` if one wants to empty the file if it *does* exist. A redirection can be applied to an empty command, and that way you don't need to launch `/usr/bin/touch`.

Comment: (BTW, `echo -n` is better replaced with `printf ''`; see the [POSIX standard for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) -- behavior is completely undefined when `-n` is passed; and, per the APPLICATION USAGE section of that standard, `printf` is suggested for new development instead).

Comment: Why not `: > trn`? This is even better as `:` (NOP) never produces any output.

Comment: I think `> trn` is quite equivalent, isn't it ?